# LoadRunner - WSS authentication: Nonce tag with encoding type Base64

Tags: web-services, wss, loadrunner

With LoadRunner I'm trying to connect with some web services operations.

I can't authenticate with:

web_service_set_security(SECURITY_TOKEN, "Type=USERNAME","LogicalName=UserCredentials", "UserName=username", "Password=pass", "PasswordOptions=SendHashed", "Add=True", LAST);

I always receive an InvalidSecurityToken error.

As I can see, I need to send "nonce" tag with encoding type Base64 but with the above function I don't do that.  Reading LoadRunner documentation I don't find anything related to that issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks your your time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered moving down a level in the OSI and going with a straight web virtual user?   In such a case you could manually have elements base64 encoded to be a part of the conversation.

Since HTTP is the carrier protocol for SOAP and REST you should have no issue recreating the web services calls in a straight web virtual user.   You'll lose the generic WSDL import capability and you will have to manage the headers yourself, but if you need more flexibility then the more open ended web virtual user may do it for you.

Thoughts?

Comment: That is my second option, but it would be easier using a function.
As a don't have any solution I'll try with your advice. Thanks!